# jQuery tablesorter refusing to working after many attempts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

my jquery tablesorter plugin has just refused to work no matter what I do. I have tried downgrading my version of jquery amongst other things but still nothing.

I'm building the table from my js file with data from an external json file.

Here's what my HTML looks like.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>A</th>
                        <th>B</th>
                        <th>DATE & TIME</th>
                        <th>C</th>
                        <th>D</th>
                        <th><button>View </button></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Here are my imported scripts

```
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>        
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/selectivizr/1.0.3b/selectivizr.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Vendors/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Vendors/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script> 
<script src="Resources/js/main.js"></script>
```

And my js where I build the table and call tablesorter

```
var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length - 30; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].name + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].summary + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + formatDate(json[i].time) + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td " + "class= text-center>" + json[i].size + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td " + "class= text-center>" + json[i].id + ', ' + json[i].id + "</td>");
        $('tbody').append(tr);
    }
```

I don't believe the fact that I'm building the table from jQuery is why I'm having this problem. I even tried creating a new table with html only but that didn't work.

This is how I call the tablesorter with jquery

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter({
        sortList: [[2,0], [3,1]]
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

THANK YOU

Comment: what happens when you run above code? Do you really need to import both tablesorter.js and tablesorter.min.js?

Comment: You're loading jQuery twice v3.2.1 and v1.12.4. Only one is needed.

Comment: @spiritwalker The table wasn't sorting accordingingly. But the issue has been fixed now. Called tablesorter at the wrong spot in my js file.

Answer (score 1):

Simple demonstration of `jQuery tablesorter` using your code. I don't see any problems.

```js
$(function () {
 var tr;
 for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  tr = $('<tr/>');
  tr.append("<td>" + i + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + i + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + i + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td " + "class= text-center>" + i + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td " + "class= text-center>" + i + ', ' + i + "</td>");
  $('tbody').append(tr);
 }

 $("#myTable").tablesorter({ widgets: ['zebra'] });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.28.15/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.28.15/css/theme.blue.css" />


<div class="table-responsive">
 <table id="myTable" cellspacing="1" class="tablesorter-blue">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>DATE & TIME</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
    <th><button>View </button></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: same here, set it up with no problem......http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/9666/

Comment: Thank you @BryanDellinger. I realised I was calling tablesort in the wrong spot in my js file. Should have called it right after I appended the table.